# Incorporating noise into machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, noise

Usually, in machine learning textbooks the $X$ dataset and the target $y$ are defined with exact values.

How about the case if the values of both $X$ and $y$ have noises: for instance, we only know that $0.5 <= x_1 <= 0.63$ but not the precise value. How could I integrate the information into the model?

Comment: If you consider Linear Regression to be machine learning (which I think you should), then you can check out [Errors-in-Variables Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models)

Answer (score 1):

There is a vast literature on this topic, you may want to have a look at this [paper](http://www.iiia.csic.es/files/pdfs/nettleton_ai_review_0.pdf), for example